# Making a rounded solid from curve

Tags: modeling, svg

Ok, so I am still a bit of a noob, mostly just watched and followed some of the Blender Guru stuff on YouTube, but now I want to try and create something I really want.

The goal is to try and turn a 2d SVG image into something I could give to a CNC Router and have it carved for me. Rather ambitious maybe, but it is the whole point right now of trying to learn how to use blender.

So I imported the SVG, and I got a lot of curves, which using Alt + C I can turn into meshes (I also used Limited Dissolve to remove some of that mess).  Now my idea, was that I would use Insert Faces, to make the shapes smaller, and raise them up a little. A cross section would then be an arch like shape.  All falls apart though because the shapes are irregular, and as soon as something gets too narrow, it starts twisting in on itself.

Is there some easy way of doing this, or am I facing a lot of manually moving vertices around?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130075/boolean-slow-looking-for-speedup-ideas/130096

Comment: Not really the same.  I could easily just extrude everything, but I want it all rounded off after, that is what is hard.