# How to extrude a complex drawing from an SVG file

Tags: mesh, modifiers, svg

I've just started using Blender. I'm trying to extrude drawings coming from an SVG file, such as the screenshot, to make stamp type of parts.
The main issue is the holes. I've tried selecting each curve, then turning it into a mesh, fill it, extrude. Then do the same with the internal curves, and finally do a Boolean subtract of the extrusions.
There are 2 problems I'm facing, one is that some Booleans only work when the extrusion is in the positive (or negative) direction, for some reason. And the other is that it's a very time consuming process and for the more complex parts (see the grapes section), it takes a while to process.
I figured I'd be able to do the boolean on the surface before extrusion, but that doesn't work.

Finally, the extrusion should ideally be with an angle, instead of 90º, I guess with the scale tool this is easily done, but if there's a way to define a specific angle I'd be interested to know.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: "I've tried selecting each curve, then turning it into a mesh, fill it, extrude.*" Why? It is a destructive irreversible process and you are turning what would otherwise be an automatic hands off process into a laborious and error prone manual work. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65555/importing-a-good-mesh/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82188/fill-along-the-front-of-a-path-of-an-svg/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82188/fill-along-the-front-of-a-path-of-an-svg/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130075/boolean-slow-looking-for-speedup-ideas/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92632/creating-an-bevel-inset-on-an-imported-svg/92635#92635

Comment: Thank you for the links, they help a lot! I'm able to fill and extrude much faster, but I can't figure out how to make the holes. For example, I can select the outer curve, 2D, cyclic, fill and extrude. But I can't select the inner curves and subtract (to make the holes).

Comment: No need to do any subtractions. Make sure they all belong to the same object (join them if they do not), also make sure they are closed and clean, as in there are no overlapping vertex or incoherent geometry. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve If they still don't fill by themselves check curve complexity, there is a known complexity limitation to the amount of vertex Blender can correctly skin in a curve